# How to use php variables in mysql query while php variable contains mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

How can I implement something like this in mysql?

```
$query1 = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE username = 'John'";
$query2 = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE username= 'Parsa'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN $query1 AND $query2";



$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query faild'.mysql_error());
$myrecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: why don't you use directly `WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 2`

Comment: Actually your way of method is totally wrong? What you have? what is your need?

Comment: @Satish Sharma: This is just a simple example. I need the right format to use queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$query1 ="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM table WHERE firstname in('John','Parsa')";


$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($query1)";
```

you have two identical queries , you could just have one . and use IN , not BETWEEN.

Comment: Yes you are right. This is just a simple example and my source is something different. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can put those 3 queries in to one query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id 
          BETWEEN
           ( SELECT id FROM table WHERE firstname = 'John' GROUP BY id ) 
          AND
           ( SELECT id FROM table WHERE firstname = 'Parsa' GROUP BY id )
         ";
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use them like this.

Answer (score -1):

although your query doesn't mean anything; you need "()" for subqueries to work.

```
$query1 = "(SELECT id FROM table WHERE username = 'John')";
$query2 = "(SELECT id FROM table WHERE username= 'Parsa')";

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN $query1 AND $query2";
```

Comment: Does it mean any thing `select id from table where id=1`

Comment: omg. i already stated it doesn't mean anything but OP is asking how to use queries in other queries. and THIS answer is for that question.

Comment: Thanks. This is my answer.

Comment: @Daan you guys are really destructive and arrogants. just because OP is giving a meaningless example, you need to downvote the answer? very mature. why don't you try to help the guy what he might be doing wrong by commenting his question. you got it all wrong. this answer is `correct` and `helps` OP in his question. this is the idea of stackoverflow. downvoting to show off your skills doesn't help anything..

Comment: I couldn't tag more people, there are 2 more anonymous downvotes.

Answer (score -1):

u can use a subselection:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN ($query1) AND ($query2)
```

But be careful: The Subselection result must be an Integer.